# Create separate QML window from C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2, qqmlcomponent

In my application I want to create another window with QML UI from C++ code.

I know it's possible to create another window using QML Window type, but I need the same thing from C++ code.

So far I managed to load my additional qml file into QQmlComponent:

```
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlComponent component(&engine);
component.loadUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/testqml.qml")));
if ( component.isReady() )
    component.create();
else
    qWarning() << component.errorString();
```

How do I display it in a separate window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone curious, I ended up solving the problem with slightly different approach.

My root QML document now looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
    MyMainWindow {
        visible: true
    }

    MyAuxiliaryWindow {
        visible: true
    }
}
```

Where `MainWindow` is a QML component with root element `ApplicationWindow` and `AuxiliaryWindow` is a component with root element `Window`.

Works just fine and you don't have to worry about loading two separate QML files.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve that using a single `QQmlEngine`. Following your code, you could do something like this:

```
QQmlEngine engine;
QQmlComponent component(&engine);
component.loadUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

if ( component.isReady() )
    component.create();
else
    qWarning() << component.errorString();

component.loadUrl(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main2.qml")));

if ( component.isReady() )
    component.create();
else
    qWarning() << component.errorString();
```

I prefer `QQmlApplicationEngine` though. This class combines a `QQmlEngine` and `QQmlComponent` to provide a convenient way to load a single QML file. So you would have fewer lines of codes if you have the opportunity of using `QQmlApplicationEngine`.

Example:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main2.qml")));

return app.exec();
```

We could also use `QQuickView`. `QQuickView` only supports loading of root objects that derive from `QQuickItem` so in this case our `qml` files couldn't start with the QML types `ApplicationWindow` or `Window` like in the examples above. So in this case, our `main` could be something like this:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
view.show();

QQuickView view2;
view2.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main2.qml"));
view2.show();

return app.exec();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, I assume the second solution will work if I use "Window" or "ApplicationWindow" QML type as a root element of my QML. Am I correct? I guess this is the thing I haven't realized - I thought I should create window from C++ somehow. Now I understand that QML rules it all.

Comment: You're right :) `QQmlApplicationEngine` does not automatically create a root window. After reading your message, I think it's a good idea to update my answer with another option: using `QQuickView`. In this case, as you know, `QQuickView` only supports loading of root objects that derive from `QQuickItem`.

Comment: For some reason your solution with one QQmlApplicationEngine and two loaded files didn't work for me, the second window just refused to show up. Maybe it was some bug in my code. Anyway, I've found a better way to solve this problem (in my case), posted it as another answer. Thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: I am sorry to hear that :( In case you want to see the code working or just to play with it, I've uploaded the code to GitHub. Anyway, I saw your new answer and it's great! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create new QQmlEngine